# How to make "Android.bp" when I include some ".h" file

Tags: android, hal

I have included "a.h" in my main.cpp file, So how to make my Android.bp file? is

Android.bp like this

```
cc_test{
    srcs:["main.cpp"]
}
```

Right? Android.bp like this  could include a.h successful?

Here is my main.cpp file

```
#include <a.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST_F(testsuite,testcase){
    #do some thing
}
int main(){
    #do some thing
}
```

Comment: [Soong](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/) (the build system that uses those `.bp` files) is similar to Bazel, so you could try following [the Bazel documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_test).

Answer (score 2):

The soong documentation is published as part of the build artifacts: https://ci.android.com/builds/latest/branches/aosp-build-tools/targets/linux/view/soong_build.html

You want `local_include_dirs: ['.']` to put the directory on the include path (or something like `local_indlude_dirs: ['include']` if `a.h` is in an `include` subdirectory).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see Android.bp documentation briefly regarding the basic structure and its components. Dan's answer gives the list of components that can be used in a bp files.
This    [LINK](https://source.android.com/setup/build)    may help.

Coming to your question: It depends.

Let's say the included file is in your local repository, then you can add

```
include_dirs: [ "path_to_your_lib" ],
```

If not, then you need to add a static or shared lib of the header file in your bp file as:

```
static_libs: [ "a_static_lib" ],
```

or 
    shared_libs: [ "a_shared_lib" ],

Hope this helps!